# Looping through array of objects in SQL Server and getting error: JSON text is not properly formatted

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm trying to loop through an array of objects within a JSON object @files, 
and insert each object from the array into a table, but I'm getting this error:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 0.

The JSON was valid using JSONLint, so I know it's not the object that I declared, unless I'm wrong. When selecting the error it highlights this in the OPENJSON WITH() statement:

**file_name NVARCHAR(100) '$.fileName',**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE files_uploadAll
    @document_id INT OUTPUT,
    @files NVARCHAR(MAX)

/*
DECLARE @document_id INT
DECLARE @files NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{  
      "files": [
      {  
            "noteId": 1,
            "documentTitle": "doc1",
            "fileName": "doc1.pdf",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "mimeType": "application/pdf",
            "documentTypeCd": "MSA",
            "userId": 1,
            "url": "http://www.url.com"
       },
       {  
            "noteId": 2,
            "documentTitle": "doc2",
            "fileName": "doc2.doc",
            "fileExtension": "doc",
            "mimeType": "application/msword",
            "documentTypeCd": "MSA",
            "userId": 1,
            "url": "http://www.url.com"
       }
    ]           
 }';
 EXECUTE files_uploadAll @files=@files, @document_id=@document_id OUTPUT
*/

AS

DECLARE @filesArray NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @filesArray = (SELECT '$.files' FROM OPENJSON(@files))

DECLARE @filesList NVARCHAR(MAX), @i int
SELECT @i=0, @filesList = @filesArray

WHILE (@i < LEN(@filesList))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @item NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @item = SUBSTRING(@filesList, @i, CHARINDEX(',',@filesList,@i)-@i)

    INSERT INTO documents
    (note_id, document_title, file_name, file_extension, mime_type, document_type_cd, user_id, url)
    SELECT note_id, document_title, file_name, file_extension, mime_type, document_type_cd, user_id, url
    FROM OPENJSON(@item)
    WITH (
        note_id INT '$.noteId',
        document_title NVARCHAR(100) '$.documentTitle',
        file_name NVARCHAR(100) '$.fileName',
        file_extension NVARCHAR(25) '$.fileExtension',
        mime_type NVARCHAR(50) '$.mimeType',
        document_type_cd CHAR(5) '$.documentTypeCd',
        user_id int '$.userId',
        url NVARCHAR(1000) '$.url'
    )
    SET @document_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    SET @i = CHARINDEX(',',@filesList,@i)+1
    IF(@i = 0) SET @i = LEN(@filesList)
END
```

Comment: Is this SQL server 2017 & compatibility level 130 or higher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY THIS:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE files_uploadAll

@document_id INT OUTPUT,
@files NVARCHAR(MAX)



AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO documents
    (note_id, document_title, file_name, file_extension, mime_type, document_type_cd, user_id, url)
    SELECT note_id, document_title, file_name, file_extension, mime_type, document_type_cd, user_id, url
    FROM OPENJSON(@files)
    WITH (
        note_id INT '$.noteId',
        document_title NVARCHAR(100) '$.documentTitle',
        file_name NVARCHAR(100) '$.fileName',
        file_extension NVARCHAR(25) '$.fileExtension',
        mime_type NVARCHAR(50) '$.mimeType',
        document_type_cd CHAR(5) '$.documentTypeCd',
        user_id int '$.userId',
        url NVARCHAR(1000) '$.url'
    )
    SET @document_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
```

Execution:

```
DECLARE @d INT
DECLARE @f NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
      {  
            "noteId": 1,
            "documentTitle": "doc1",
            "fileName": "doc1.pdf",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "mimeType": "application/pdf",
            "documentTypeCd": "MSA",
            "userId": 1,
            "url": "http://www.url.com"
       },
       {  
            "noteId": 2,
            "documentTitle": "doc2",
            "fileName": "doc2.doc",
            "fileExtension": "doc",
            "mimeType": "application/msword",
            "documentTypeCd": "MSA",
            "userId": 1,
            "url": "http://www.url.com"
       }
    ]';
 EXECUTE files_uploadAll @files=@f, @document_id=@d OUTPUT
```

Here if you notice I have just added array as param & with no loop we can insert data with performance.

Comment: you are asking them to change the json file. you have to provide solution with their json file.

Comment: not changing json but removing redundant wrapper, being a dev we know it is easier & efficient to remove at app layer as Serialization is done one entity having collection of files named files. Just send one level less to db is doing nothing at app level. If code can't be changed i can change answer but it is more efficient this way

Comment: I must heavily disagree! 1) It is very easy to solve this on query level, see my answer. 2) Very often we cannot change the sending app. 3) Even more often we do not want to change the sending app. 4) We do not want to mix differently styled data 5) and - assumably - there is existing data already and 6) you do not know, if this wrapper is *redundant*.

Comment: Fair enough, both are assumptions yet. Depends on how you see, I work end-to-end from ui to code to db so seems more performative to `remove redundant` wrapper in calling stored procedure(no class changes required `obj.files` instead of `obj`) since in long run we have to maintain the mess. Sending only what you require is always done when do performance tuning.

Comment: This worked perfectly! It was much easier to work with the data by removing that wrapper, and it easily added to my table. Thanks!

Comment: @hypnagogia, I am glad it worked for you. You can always upvote or mark as answer if it helps

Answer (score 5):

No need for any loops and no need to change the input. this can easily be solved with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(JSON_QUERY(@files,'$.files'))
WITH (
    note_id INT '$.noteId',
    document_title NVARCHAR(100) '$.documentTitle',
    file_name NVARCHAR(100) '$.fileName',
    file_extension NVARCHAR(25) '$.fileExtension',
    mime_type NVARCHAR(50) '$.mimeType',
    document_type_cd CHAR(5) '$.documentTypeCd',
    user_id int '$.userId',
    url NVARCHAR(1000) '$.url'
);
```

The return is a simple resultset you can use for any operations:

```
+---------+----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------+
| note_id | document_title | file_name | file_extension | mime_type          | document_type_cd | user_id | url                |
+---------+----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------+
| 1       | doc1           | doc1.pdf  | pdf            | application/pdf    | MSA              | 1       | http://www.url.com |
+---------+----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------+
| 2       | doc2           | doc2.doc  | doc            | application/msword | MSA              | 1       | http://www.url.com |
+---------+----------------+-----------+----------------+--------------------+------------------+---------+--------------------+
```

I use `JSON_QUERY` to get into `$.files`. `OPENJSON` will return the *array-of-objects*, while the `WITH` clause will transform the object to named and typed columns.

Comment: This worked for returning the result set but I needed data to be inserted into a table which contains foreign keys so I used Pranav's solution below. I found that removing the wrapper wasn't interfering with the data I was going to be sending in.

Comment: @hypnagogia You can insert all at once directly from this statement? Typically such things are done against a staging table (2-step-import).

Comment: It actually did work, I was able to insert into the table by using AJAX call multiplexing, I sent a request with an array of objects and got all data in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

As you are having root element in your JSON, you need to call OPENJSON with root element, as given below. You will not get error now.

[Refer to JSON support in SQL Server 2016](https://codingsight.com/json-support-in-sql-server-2016/)

```
DECLARE @document_id INT
DECLARE @files NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{  
      "files": [
      {  
            "noteId": 1,
            "documentTitle": "doc1",
            "fileName": "doc1.pdf",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "mimeType": "application/pdf",
            "documentTypeCd": "MSA",
            "userId": 1,
            "url": "http://www.url.com"
       },
       {  
            "noteId": 2,
            "documentTitle": "doc2",
            "fileName": "doc2.doc",
            "fileExtension": "doc",
            "mimeType": "application/msword",
            "documentTypeCd": "MSA",
            "userId": 1,
            "url": "http://www.url.com"
       }
    ] '          

SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@files,'$.files');
```

Comment: This might work, but `OPENJSON` will return a table, quite some overhead for a root element. You might want to check my answer. It's better to use `JSON_QUERY` and then `OPENJSON` on this return value.